# Dynamically unpivot table within Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, unpivot

I have a table with several hundred columns that I need to unpivot. All of the columns that need to be unpivoted start with 'SIM_'. I know how to do this statically (example below), but I'd like a dynamic solution - as the number of columns that need be be unpivot is both long and may change over time.

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    (SELECT
        ID, 
        NAME,
        SIM_1, 
        SIM_2, 
        SIM_3
    FROM
        SAMPLE_TABLE
    ) T UNPIVOT(SIM_RESULT FOR SIM IN (SIM_1, SIM_2, SIM_3))
```

Comment: The dynamic solution would be to generate the SQL statement dynamically.  Either one time (run a query against `user_tab_columns` and copy & paste the results into the query) or explicitly use dynamic SQL in your stored procedure.

Comment: like this: SELECT
    *
FROM
    (SELECT
        *
    FROM
        SAMPLE_TABLE
    ) T UNPIVOT(SIM_RESULT FOR SIM IN (SELECT
                                            ALL_TAB_COLS.COLUMN_NAME
                                        FROM
                                            ALL_TAB_COLS 
                                        WHERE
                                            ALL_TAB_COLS.TABLE_NAME = 'SAMPLE_TABLE' AND
                                            ALL_TAB_COLS.COLUMN_NAME LIKE ('SIM_%'))

Comment: No.  I mean literally run the `all_tab_cols` query to get the list and then copy & paste the static list into the static query you've built (you'd need to manually re-run the query to re-build the list when additional columns are added).  Or make the query entirely dynamic in your stored procedure but that can get somewhat complicated depending on what you're doing with the results of the query.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could (re)create a view when there is a need to refresh the list of columns. This way you will have the accurate list of columns and a way to show real data. It does the unpivoting of all columns (like SIM_%) in the time of execution.

```
/*    sample table and data
CREATE TABLE AA_TST
    (ID NUMBER(6), SIM_A VARCHAR2(20), SIM_B VARCHAR2(20), SIM_C VARCHAR2(20), SIM_D VARCHAR2(20), SIM_E VARCHAR2(20));

INSERT INTO AA_TST  VALUES(1, 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E');
INSERT INTO AA_TST  VALUES(2, 'AA', 'BB', 'CC', 'DD', 'EE');
INSERT INTO AA_TST  VALUES(3, 'AAA', 'BBB', 'CCC', 'DDD', 'EEE');
*/

Declare
        col_list        VarChar2(1000);
        myViewSQL       VarChar2(1000);
Begin
        SELECT  LISTAGG(column_name, ', ') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY column_name) 
        INTO    col_list
        FROM    all_tab_columns
        WHERE   table_name  = 'AA_TST' And     
                column_name LIKE 'SIM_%';
    --
        myViewSQL := 'SELECT VALUE_NAME, VALUE_OF FROM AA_TST UNPIVOT (VALUE_OF FOR VALUE_NAME IN(' || col_list || '))';
        execute immediate 'CREATE or replace VIEW AA_TST_VIEW AS ' || myViewSQL;
End;
/
SELECT * FROM AA_TST_VIEW;
--
--  R e s u l t 
--
--  anonymous block completed
--  VALUE_NAME VALUE_OF           
--  ---------- --------------------
--  SIM_A      A                    
--  SIM_B      B                    
--  SIM_C      C                    
--  SIM_D      D                    
--  SIM_E      E                    
--  SIM_A      AA                   
--  SIM_B      BB                   
--  SIM_C      CC                   
--  SIM_D      DD                   
--  SIM_E      EE                   
--  SIM_A      AAA                  
--  SIM_B      BBB                  
--  SIM_C      CCC                  
--  SIM_D      DDD                  
--  SIM_E      EEE                  
--  
--   15 rows selected
```